# How to display an image in place of Toolbar layout in Master/Detail flow (Android Studio)?

Tags: android, android-layout, master-detail

I have Started to create an app using Master/detail flow.I want to display different images in Toolbar layout for different items in the list.Can anyone please me.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you used the Android Studio generated master/detail activity.
In the main activity you can find a Recycle view inflated from this resource "item_list". 
You can overwrite the adapter for it.

There are a lot of good tutorials about recycle views. For example http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

The Toolbar is actually just another layout thanks to Lollipop. So you can define a Layout with any number of View component that you want including images and then replace the Toolbar generated by the wizard with the custom Toolbar that you create.

Here is an example custom_toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/custom_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:padding="0dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_profile_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"        
        android:text="John Doe"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:src="@drawable/John_doe_image.jpg"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
             />

             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profile_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="john_doe@gmail.com"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        </LinearLayout>   
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

With this you can now go to the layout that has the Toolbar that you want to replace. Delete that toolbar and replace it your custom Toolbar like this

```
 <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"
```

Hope that helps.
Thanks